# relay working problem

Tags: relay

I am using circuits.io with Arduino. my program is to blink the led with 2 seconds delay. The led in the circuit blink according to program but the bulb does not blink. I am very weak in electronics. This is what i starting to learn from the scratch. the problem here is the bulb doesnt blink according to the program. which is meant to blink. i have uploaded the circuit image below.. . thanks in advanced.

[image: Please check the Image here]

Comment: Your layout makes no sense.  Please post a schematic showing all the circuit connections and the power input to the arduino.

Comment: you show no ground connection between arduino and relay, does this represent what you have?

Comment: this layout... use the schematic editor.

Comment: In the circuit.io layouts that I have seen, they do connect power to the Arduino board.  You have yet to do this. (There are other problems, but let's start with the obvious one 1st.)

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted this, because even after three hours of being pointed to a lack of clear schematic, you haven't tried to improve your diagram. Thus, no answer can be given, and your question holds no value in itself.

Comment: sorry i am lacking in explaining the question , m trying, as i said i am very new to electronics , what knowledge i have till date is i am using. 
i do not have any schematics , i dont even know how to design it. what i am trying is to play with arduino boards hence ii am trying things only on circuits.io.
guys what i can provide is , the link of my circuit.

https://circuits.io/circuits/3117748-the-unnamed-circuit

u can start the simulation and check that how it is working. 
i just need to blink the Bulb like the led in my circuit blinks. please take a trial from the link..

Comment: If you search for "arduino drive relay" you will get plenty of information. Note that all the circuits will have a diode across the relay: that is required to prevent other components from being damaged.

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-1/electric-circuits/

Comment: @AndrewMorton : ur suggestion helped me. i got the answer , user:emfields diagram helped me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wire up your circuit as shown below, the bulb and the LED should flash together.

[image]